# Find $\int_{-1}^{1} x^2\sqrt {(1-(-A+x)^2)*(1-x^2)}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^{1} x^2\sqrt {(1-(-A+x)^2)*(1-x^2)}\mathrm dx$$

Where $A \in \Bbb R^+$

I need to find a definite integral on symmetric interval. 
I know that I would appreciate any help or link to literature I can find methods how to solve.
Thanks

Comment: What is the interval?

Comment: interval is from -k^2 to k^2, where k is a real number. k is relatively small. First mention I found on internet is http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticPi3/introductions/IncompleteEllipticIntegrals/ShowAll.html     in 6th line but I would probably need some detailed study.

Comment: @TimBeno The function inside the square-root is less than zero over part of the integration interval, so the integrand isn't real-valued. Are you sure you wrote the integral down correctly?